# Grocery or Goods

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Grocery - items of food sold in a grocery store (Google). But suppose I bought a few cleaning items along with the food stuff can the collection still be called grocery? Or maybe goods ?

Comment: If the shop sells items you wouldn't class as groceries, are you sure it's a grocers/grocery store?

Comment: I’d call the collection ***groceries*** not *grocery*.

Comment: Sounds like you bought *sundries*.

Answer (score 2):

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grocer) defines a **grocer** as

> NOUN
>   A person who sells food and small household goods.

So groceries are not restricted to food items.

Answer (score 0):

"shopping" or, in Scotland, "messages".

From The Scotsman newspaper (usually regarded as the leading newspaper in Scotland)

"The phrase used was, in most cases, ‘go the messages’, although it was used less frequently as a noun to refer to the shopping that people had bought that day.
   It’s believed that the phrase itself originates from either messenger boys with their large bags - naturally, the daily shopping was carried in a large, sturdy bag - or from the bags themselves. In some cases, messenger boys would deliver the ‘messages’ to people unable to manage it themselves, using a bike and the aforementioned sturdy bags."
https://www.scotsman.com/lifestyle/scottish-word-of-the-day-messages-1-2466057

From the Scottish National Dictionary

"MESSAGE, n. Also messige. Sc. usage: a visit to a shop to make purchases, most commonly in pl. of the purchases made, one's shopping. Gen.Sc. Phr. to go the messages, to do one's shopping. Comb. message boy, an errand-boy. Gen.Sc. "
http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/message

Compare also with French, "faire des commissions" = to run errands

Comment: Hi Owain, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *shopping* (linked to the source) and say why it suits the context. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: Since *messages* seems an unusual usage for this context, it's particularly important that you provide evidence to support this, so that we can be sure you're not just trolling us. :-)